# CGPath and Quartz 2D

Tags: iphone, sdk, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I want to create a triangle using Quartz 2D functions. The 3 edges of the triangle should be in different colors. I am able to create the triangle but not able to set the color of each edge or subpath separately. Any suggestions or sample code are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making separate (line) paths for each side.